# when revoking token getting response account not found

Tags: node.js, oauth

**`when revoking token getting response account not found even though account is in DB.`**

After registering a user and refreshing the token, I was trying revoke the previous token but, got an error message "Account not found" but the respective account is present in mongo collection.

**`Authorize.js`**

```
function authorize(roles = []) {
  // roles param can be a single role string (e.g. Role.User or 'User')
  // or an array of roles (e.g. [Role.Admin, Role.User] or ['Admin', 'User'])
  if (typeof roles === "string") {
    roles = [roles];
  }

  return [
    // authenticate JWT token and attach user to request object (req.user)
    jwt({ secret, algorithms: ["HS256"] }),

    // authorize based on user role
    async (req, res, next) => {
      console.log("start ");
      const account = await db.Account.findById(req.user.id);
      const refreshTokens = await db.RefreshToken.find({ account: account.id });

      if (!account || (roles.length && !roles.includes(account.role))) {
        // account no longer exists or role not authorized
        console.log("role ");
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
      }

      // authentication and authorization successful
      req.user.role = account.role;
      console.log("token11");
      req.user.ownsToken = (token) => {
        console.log("token");
        !!refreshTokens.find((x) => x.token === token);
      };

      next();
    },];}
```

here the token is verified to check its authorization.

**`server.js`**

```
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const errorHandler = require('_middleware/error-handler');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// allow cors requests from any origin and with credentials
app.use(cors({ origin: (origin, callback) => callback(null, true), credentials: true }));

// api routes
app.use('/accounts', require('./accounts/accounts.controller'));

// swagger docs route
app.use('/api-docs', require('_helpers/swagger'));

// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// start server
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (process.env.PORT || 80) : 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

this the server file with routing to different API's

**account.service.js**

```
async function revokeToken({ token, ipAddress }) {
  console.log("services");
  const refreshToken = await getRefreshToken(token);

  // revoke token and save
  refreshToken.revoked = Date.now();
  refreshToken.revokedByIp = ipAddress;

  await refreshToken.save();
}
```

function to revoke the given token

**account.controller.js**

```
function revokeToken(req, res, next) {
  console.log("here.......");
  // accept token from request body or cookie
  const token = req.body.token || req.cookies.refreshToken;
  const ipAddress = req.ip;

  if (!token) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Token is required" });

  // users can revoke their own tokens and admins can revoke any tokens
  if (!req.user.ownsToken(token) && req.user.role !== Role.Admin) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  }

  accountService
    .revokeToken({ token, ipAddress })
    .then(() => res.json({ message: "Token revoked" }))
    .catch(next);
}
```

revoke token request to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be providing old token in the body. Try to authenticate again and then provide new token. It may work.

Comment: Thanks I was exactly doing this. It worked now.